# Deletar dados com relação many to many no Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou tendo um problema ao deletar dados associados no Laravel. Tenho as tabelas users, registros e tags. [image: modelo relacional]

Como podem ver a tabela users se conecta com registros, enquanto uma tabela pivot(registro_has_tags) conecta as tabelas registro e tags.

O problema ocorre quando eu tento apagar um user, já que eu também quero apagar os dados da tabela registros referente aquele usuário, porém, quando tento fazer isso recebo uma mensagem de erro por conta da associação muitos para muitos entre tags e registros.

não faço ideia de como posso resolver isso no Laravel

Definição dos models:

User...

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function registro()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Registro::class); //User tem muitos registros
    }

    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
```

Registros...

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Registro extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 
        'descricao', 
        'data_vencimento', 
        'valor', 
        'tipo', 
        'status'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        // Retorna a associação com base no objeto
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class); //Perternce ao objeto usuário
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'registros_has_tags');
    }
}
```

Tags...

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'nome',
        'descricao'
    ];

    public function registro()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Registro::class, 'registros_has_tags');
    }

}
```

Tentei realizar a operação pegando o id do user

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        try{

            $user = $this->user->findOrFail($id);
            $user->registro()->detach();
            $user->delete($id);

            return response()->json([
                'data'=> [
                    'msg'=> 'Usuário deletado com sucesso!'
                ]
            ], 200);

        }catch(\Exception $e){
            return response()->json(['erro: ' => $e->getMessage()], 401);
        }
    }
```

As migrations da api são:

users...

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Registros...

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTableRegistros extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('registros', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->text('descricao');
            $table->date('data_vencimento');
            $table->float('valor');
            $table->enum('tipo', ['D', 'C', 'P', 'R']); 
            $table->boolean('status')->nullable(true); //Campo pode ser nulo
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('registros');
    }
}
```

Tags...

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTableTags extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('nome');
            $table->string('descricao');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('tags');
    }
}
```

Tabela pivot(registros_has_tags)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTableRegistrosHasTags extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('registros_has_tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('registros_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('tags_id');

            $table->foreign('registros_id')->references('id')->on('registros');
            $table->foreign('tags_id')->references('id')->on('tags');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('registros_has_tags');
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloque na pergunta as definições dos *models* e como tentou fazer a exclusão.

Comment: Beleza Anderson. Acabei de colocar as definições dos models.

Comment: Já cogitou definir a exclusão em cascata nas suas migrations?

Comment: Na verdade já tentei sim. Não sei se eu usei a exclusão de forma correta, mas não funcionou

Comment: Coloque as migrations por favor

Comment: Algumas notas, no modelo user o método registo deveria ser registos (um para muitos), o método detach() aplica-se a many to many que é o relacionamento que existe entre registos e tags e não a one to many  que é o tipo de relacionamento entre user e registros

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas Jorge, irei corrigir o erro assim que possível. Obrigado também pela explicação sobre o detach()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Galera, consegui resolver o problema usando o onDelete('cascade') nas migrations

ficou o seguinte:

`$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')`

Agradeço a ajuda de todos :)

Comment: isso que eu iria falar